# eyecon color picker pops behind jqgrid (jqueryui) dialog on edit form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, colors, jqgrid, picker

I would like to know if has anyone used eyecon color picker with jqueryui dialog? Everything works fine but whenever the user clicks on the textbox to show the color picker, the color picker appears behind the jqueryui dialog. It seems related to z-index property. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you include JavaScript code which you currently use? Do you tried with CSS `.colorpicker {z-index:1100;}` or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

edit colorpicker.css and specify a z-index:

```
.colorpicker {
    width: 356px;
    height: 176px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../images/colorpicker_background.png);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: none;
    z-index:1005;
}
```